# Failed to reconnect to ignite cluster on client side node

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, ignite

I was working with Ignite cache. I have a server node running on server and few remote client nodes and one client node at my local. When I run the jar file of my spring boot application, it gives and `class o.a.i.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@5010be6`

I checked the other client nodes and all of them are connected to server. Because of this my jar file isn't running.
I am attaching the logs of this error.

```
2021-04-28 12:07:50.170  WARN [project,,,] 2263 --- [project] o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi  : Failed to reconnect to cluster (will retry): class o.a.i.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@5010be6
2021-04-28 12:08:20.969  WARN [project,,,] 2263 --- [project] o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi  : Failed to reconnect to cluster (will retry): class o.a.i.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@5010be6
2021-04-28 12:08:53.732  WARN [project,,,] 2263 --- [project] o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi  : Failed to reconnect to cluster (will retry): class o.a.i.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@5010be6
2021-04-28 12:09:27.436  WARN [athens,,,] 2263 --- [project] o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi  : Failed to reconnect to cluster (will retry): class o.a.i.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@5010be6
2021-04-28 12:09:59.415  WARN [project,,,] 2263 --- [project] o.a.i.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi  : Failed to reconnect to cluster (will retry): class o.a.i.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@5010be6
```

Comment: Is it possible to share a full error message? Do you have any exceptions on the server side?

Comment: @VladimirPligin There is no exception on server side. Sorry can't share full log

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have are using some classes in your IgniteConfiguration which are not present on all of the nodes.

Since there are no stack traces, we can't know which one specifically. Make sure that all nodes have all dependencies on classpath.